# Resulting nulls on full join not being replaced

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of select queries using full join (required) and would like to replace the resulting nulls with something else (in the following example, it should be "empty").
For the first column (and all others, honestly) I have tried using isnull(), coallesce(), case when and even try_convert, but the result is always null. I'm ok with null, as in this particular case means that the results from the first query don't exist the second query, which is my goal.
There are following, identical queries, also full join 'd, so a line in the first query may not be in the second query but may be in the third of fourth queries.

Here is the select statement

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Isnull(1, 'empty') AS SubGroup
               , table2.lineintid AS OrderByThis2nd
               , table2.HeaderStamp AS HeaderLink
               , table2.linestamp AS LineID
               , table2.lprocessname AS LineProcName
               , table2.lprocessno AS LineProcNumber
               , table2.productid AS ProdId
               , table2.prodamount AS QTT
               , table2.prodval AS UnitPrice
        FROM   table2 (nolock)
               INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.headerstamp = table1.headerstamp
        WHERE  table1.lprocessname = 'Phase 1')Proc1L
       FULL JOIN (SELECT Isnull(2, 'empty') AS SubGroup
                         , table2.lineintid AS OrderByThis2nd
                         , table2.linestamp AS LineID
                         , table2.prevlstamp AS PrecedingLine
                         , table2.lprocessname AS LineProcName
                         , table2.lprocessno AS LineProcNumber
                         , table2.productid AS ProdId
                         , table2.prodamount AS QTT
                         , table2.prodval AS UnitPrice
                  FROM   table2 (nolock)
                         INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.headerstamp = table1.headerstamp
                  WHERE  table1.lprocessname = 'Phase 2'
                     AND Year(table2.linedate) = '2018')Proc2L ON Proc1L.LineID = Proc2L.PrecedingLine
ORDER  BY 1 DESC
          , 2
```

This database is in MS SQL 2014.
Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using isnull function in the outer query. Instead of "select * from" use "select isnull(col1, 'x'), etc from

Comment: You have many questionable things going on here. First is randomly using NOLOCK. You may want read this before you continue using that hint all over the place. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You have functions in your where predicates which negate any indexes. You are using select *. And you are ordering by ordinal position. This is truly awful. Consider what happens if you actually put in the columns you want returned and the order of columns changes....your order by is now by the wrong column. And a little formatting goes a LONG way. :)

Comment: Try writing to a new table and then updating the null values in that table to 'empty'. Then select from the new table.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze thanks for your tip, it works perfectly! How should I mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your reading suggestion. The software in question is written in Visual Fox Pro and since it can have concurrent connections to the same table, every query has a `nolock`; not being an expert led me to follow that practice. Ordering may not be optimal, but returns the needed results because table#.lineintid is the unique incremental id for the record; the Subgroup just sets an order on the Phases...

Comment: @SeanLange oh, and a special thank you for correcting the question's format. Being the first post in the community, took me some time to understand the process. Will pay more attention next time!

Comment: @Paulo I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ISNULL function in the outer query. Instead of

```
select * from
```

use

```
Select isnull(col1, 'x'), etc 
from
```